# WPF ListView item is selected only after MessageBox is displayed

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a strange problem: I am trying to select an item in a WPF ListView, like this:

```
int lineIndex = 123;
scrollView.ScrollToVerticalOffset(lineIndex);
myListView.SelectedIndex = lineIndex;
```

But the selection is lost for some reason. Only if I display a MessageBox before the select statement, the selection works, like this:

```
int lineIndex = 123;
scrollView.ScrollToVerticalOffset(lineIndex);
MessageBox.Show("msg");
myListView.SelectedIndex = lineIndex;
```

After I click the `OK` button on the message box, the index gets selected. Is this because a message box blocks the UI thread while it is displayed? If so, how can I simulate this behavior without displaying the message box?

Answer (score 0):

Is using the SelectedItem property available to you instead of using the scrollviewer inside the listview? The following code demonstrates selecting the 20th item in the list and scrolling to it's offset.

```
<Window x:Class="testt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testt"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="myListView"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="40" Click="Button_Click">click</Button>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind

```
using System.Windows;

namespace testt
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                myListView.Items.Add("A test item " + i.ToString());
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int lineIndex = 20;
            var item = myListView.Items[lineIndex];
            myListView.ScrollIntoView(item);
            myListView.SelectedItem = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use `ScrollIntoView` because my ListView is using data virtualization. The items of the ListView are instances of a class. It seems to be some kind of issue with the UI/worker thread. Because when I display the message box and click `OK`, the UI/worker thread continues and the item gets selected properly..